# Get cookies from website using python (Safari)

Tags: python, cookies

I try to get cookies from a website. Reading a bit on this topic on other StackOverflow posts I came up with this code because other code pieces did not work either.

```py
import requests

s = requests.Session()
print(s.get("https://instagram.com").cookies.get_dict())
```

Unfortunately, it returns an empty dictionary.

I already tried it with `browser_cookie3` but it either did not work or it is not supporting `Safari`.

Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the cookies from your `requests.Session()`. The request will not execute any javascript code so there are no cookies to read. That is why you are getting a empty dictionary.

If the cookies were set on server side itself you would be able to read them.

Between Browser Cookies 3 Currently supports Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge, and Chromium.

Comment: Okay is there a way then to get the cookies from the Safari Browser or is it just Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge and Chromium only?

Comment: Do you want to extract already existing cookies from your browser?

Comment: yes. I know where they are when looking into the console of Safari but I do not know how to get them in code in Python...